# 1D green function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I want to solve the problem

$$ \frac {\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} + \alpha \frac {\partial u} {\partial t} = f(t)$$

$$u(0)=u'(0)=0$$

$$f(t)=exp(-\beta t)$$

Using distributions (Green functions).

So i did

$$ \frac {\partial^2G}{\partial t^2} + \alpha \frac {\partial G} {\partial t} = \delta (t-s)$$
$$G(0)=G'(0)=0$$

When I solved this as I would usually do, by solving the equation for $t \gt s$ and $t \lt s$ and then giving conditions for $G$ (continuous as it is in 1D, with a jump in the derivative and satisfying the homogeneous bondary conditions) I end up with $G=0$, and that is nonsense. So, how would you do this?

If you solve this equations directly, you can show that it actually has a solution. What is my problem? Maybe the green function is not always continuous, but then I don't get why I always ask that condition in order to solve the PDE in 1D using distributions...

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'll respond to your concerns about generalities: the Green's function for a problem of order $n$ has a jump in the derivative of order $n-1$, and the derivatives of order less than or equal to $n-2$ are all continuous. So for a second order equation, the Green's function is continuous but not differentiable.

In this case you want to have $G$ such that $G''+\alpha G'=0$ except that at $s$ there is a jump in $G'$ of size $1$. Based on that equation, up until $s$, $G$ will simply remain zero. Then at $s$, $G$ stays the same but $G'$ jumps up to $1$. In other words, to handle $t>s$ you need to solve the problem

$$G''+\alpha G'=0,G(s)=0,G'(s)=1.$$

The solution to this problem is *not* zero, and this is what you need to find.

A nice tip that simplifies life a little bit: in an IVP for an autonomous equation, you do not need to introduce the $s$, because $G$ will always depend only on $t-s$. Instead you can simply put $\delta(t)$ on the right side and be done with it (assuming the initial conditions are at zero).

Comment: A question though... isn't G supposed to be symmetric?

Comment: @Lessa121 $G$ is symmetric in the sense that $G(t,s)=G(s,t)$...which means I may have made a minor error. (I am used to the autonomous situation where there is no $s$.) Hang on...

Comment: I'm still missing that that in this case $G(t,s)=G(s,t)$, as the solution depends on $s$ being grater or less than $t$...

Comment: @Lessa121 Now I remember what happened. Here the differential operator is not self-adjoint, which is why $G$ is not symmetric.

Comment: Great! I think I'm getting it now... If you don't mind explaining it, how do you know that the operator is not self-adjoint?

Comment: When you integrate by parts to calculate the adjoint, the $d/dt$ changes sign when it is moved to the other term. With $d^2/dt^2$ (which *is* self-adjoint, if the boundary conditions are appropriate, such as homogeneous Dirichlet or Neumann conditions), there are two sign changes which cancel out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: @Lessa121 You're welcome. Also I realized this morning that there is a nice physical interpretation to what I said in this special situation. These second order linear constant coefficient systems are commonly thought of as spring-mass systems, where the first order term corresponds to friction (if its coefficient is positive). This friction term carries an "arrow of time": going forward in time it slows the system down, but going backward in time it speeds the system up.

Comment: @Lessa121 (Cont.) This is reflected in the mathematics in several places, including the minus sign in the adjoint of the differential operator, because the adjoint is the operator for going backward in time.